# Check for duplicates in list and print out

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to check the list and give the duplicates out.
Somehow doesn't work.

```
some_list = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'b', 'd', 'm', 'n', 'n']

duplicates = []
for value in some_list:
    if some_list.count(value) > 1:
        if value not in duplicates:
            duplicates.append(value)

print(duplicates)
```

It should output

```
['b', 'n']
```

But it gives only the 'n' out

```
['n']
```

Comment: I just ran your output and it works fine for me

Comment: Could not replicate, I get `['b', 'n']` as expected.

Comment: [Works for me](https://tio.run/##RY3BCsMgEETv@xV7s4ESKLkV2h8poVg1VDCrRA306202hjiHYZmdfRt@6etpKCX62bydjQkf@BJSXFF82NQ5abaZjaqNADoHZ5VMJvLZCJNfcJUuG7SEJ/IOuMlOLemVz5Que7XDJ95q5ahVAvnElPaidVgt72UIhvRBAwiL3dht35XyBw).

Answer (score 1):

I just ran your code and it seems to work fine for me.

```
some_list = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'b', 'd', 'm', 'n', 'n']

duplicates = []
for value in some_list:
    if some_list.count(value) > 1:
        if value not in duplicates:
            duplicates.append(value)

print(duplicates)
```

---

Output: `['b', 'n']`

If you want a more succinct way to accomplish the same thing, you can use set() to get the unique items, then list() to convert it into a list:

```
duplicates = list(set([item for item in some_list if some_list.count(item) > 1]))
```

---

Output: `['b', 'n']`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Could the IDE be the problem?

Comment: I really doubt it, but if you don't get the same output from the same code as I do, what IDE are you using and what version of Python?